# VueJS - React in another component on an event

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm wondering if this is possible..

I have two components:

1. Companies
2. DataView

`Companies` shows the current company that the user is subscribed to, and displays a list of possible companies that the user can use.

`DataView`  displays all of the data in a table based on the company (This is stored within a session inside PHP and returned)

**What I want to do:**

When a user changes a company, this sends a request to the PHP file and updates the view with the selected company. However, this does not effect the table in `DataView` what I want to do is make the application so that whenever a new company is selected, it sends another API call to the server and fetches the result based on the selected company (though the session)..

**What I've looked into**

Inside my `DataView` I have the following method:

```
fetchTheData() {
   // Fetch from the API 
   // store the results 

}
```

Now can I add a `watches` inside here that listens to data changing on another view? Essentially, it can literally just be a trigger as the server handles all of the data it returns.

EDIT (Code):
companies.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="dv">

      <div class="header-block header-block-nav">
        <ul class="nav-profile">
            <li class="profile dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="name">{{current.name}}</span>
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu profile-dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" style="left:10px;">
                <a v-for="company in companies" @click="handleChange(company)">
                    {{company.name}}
                </a>

              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>


  </div>
</template>


<script>

  import Vue from 'vue'
  import axios from 'axios'

  axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

  export default {


      data() {

        return {
            model: {},
            current: {},
            companies: {},
          }
      },

      mounted(){
        this.fetchIndexData();

      },


      created() {

      },

      methods: {

          handleChange(company) {
              //console.log(company.name);

              axios.post(`/api/user/companies/set`, {
                  companyId: company.id,
              }).then(function (response) {
                 console.log(response.data);
                 return;

              });

              return;
          },

          fetchIndexData() {

            var vm = this;
            axios.get(`/user/companies/get`)
              .then(function(response) {
                  Vue.set(vm.$data, 'current', response.data.current);
                  Vue.set(vm.$data, 'companies', response.data.all);
                  console.log(response);
              });
          }


      }

  }


</script>
```

DataView.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="dv">
    <div class="dv-header">

      <div class="dv-header-search col-md-3 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
        <input type="text" class="dv-header-input form-control boxed"
          placeholder="Search"
          v-model="query.search_input"
          @keyup="fetchIndexData()">
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <transition
        name="custom-classes-transition"
        enter-active-class="animated tada"
        leave-active-class="animated bounceOutRight">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th v-for="column in columns" @click="toggleOrder(column)">
                        {{column}}
                    </th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                 </tr>

             </thead>

             <tbody>
                <tr v-for="row in model">
                    <td v-for="(value, key) in row">{{value}}</td>
                    <td>
                      <a :href="'/users/' + row.id + '/edit/'" class="btn-table btn-edit btn-primary btn-xs">
                            <i class="edit-button fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </a>

                      <a :href="'/users/' + row.id + '/delete/'" class="btn-table btn-delete btn-primary btn-xs">
                          <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </a>
                      <!--
                      <a :href="'/users/' + row.id + '/edit/'">
                          Edit
                      </a> -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
  </transition>
  </div>
</div>
</template>


<script>

  import Vue from 'vue'
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {

      props: ['source', 'title'],

      data() {

        return {
            model: {},
            columns: {},

            query: {
                page: 1,
                column: 'id',
                direction: 'desc',
                per_page: 15,
                search_column: 'id',
                search_input: ''
            },

          }
      },

      mounted(){
        console.log("here");
        this.fetchIndexData();
      },

      created() {
          this.fetchIndexData();
      },

      methods: {

          next() {



          },

          prev() {


          },

          fetchIndexData() {
            var vm = this;
            axios.get(`${this.source}?search_input=${this.query.search_input}&page=${this.query.page}`)
              .then(function(response) {
                  Vue.set(vm.$data, 'model', response.data.model)
                  Vue.set(vm.$data, 'columns', response.data.columns)
              });
          }


      }

  }


</script>
```

Basically, when `handleChange` is triggered on inside `companies.vue` I want to trigger `fetchIndexData` inside DataView.vue

Comment: 2 common options are to use the Vue object as a global event bus, or use Vuex.

Comment: @EricGuan Sorry - Do you have any examples by any chance?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication. https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html

Comment: When the user changes the company, is that request done via AJAX or are you refreshing the page? If you provided some code examples it would help because what you're trying to do shouldn't be hard with VueJS.

Comment: @AndreLiem Hi, I have updated my question with some code. Please take a look and tell me if it's possible just using VueJS

Comment: Yes that's possible, so it looks like you might be running into issues with your data not being "reactive"? 

e.g. - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: @AndreLiem So essentially, I store the data as `Global` where I define `var vm = new Vue({` and this should allow it to be "reactive"?

Comment: @Phorce sorry on the late reply. I think I get it now... using vuex would solve this issue. The simpler one would be using the EventBus system to dispatch and coordinate the updates. Vuex isn't that hard to setup and might be the easiest long term solution if this application grows.

Comment: @Phorce Yeah, vuex will make things easier long term, it's a good investment either way to learn!